# Problemas con Springboot , vue y heroku

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, spring-boot, heroku

Hola cree un proyecto Springboot en STS y dentro de carpeta llamada frontend que continene la parte con vue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pude alojar mi proyecto de CRUD en heroku,pero con algunos problemas:

1)para que la pagina corra, tuve que pasar los archivos generados en /dist a la carpeta public , y esta a su vez ponerla con el resto de los archivos de la parte de SpringBoot , recien ahi pude visualizar todo en heroku,pero perdi la parte de css que funcionaba cuando corria de manera local.

2)Al proyecto lo realice con MySQL,tuve que cambiarlo a postgresql para heroku y no realiza ninguna operacion, asi que modifique pom.xml  agregandole las dependencias de postgresql y aplication.properties( tengo que pasarle los parametros como con MySQL? los que me da en view credential en heroku?)

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el repositorio de github
https://github.com/marianopuchetta/Crud-Spring-Vue

gracias.

y una captura de heroku 
si alguien me puede ayudar y necesita que le cuente un poco mas no hay problema,saludos y gracias.

Comment: Te comento que no tienes por qué cambiar a postgresql ya que heroku también tiene para trabajar con mysql el add-on se llama clearDB. Por otra parte, tampoco veo necesario pasar las cosas de dist a la carpeta public, para éste caso en específico lo que puedes hacer es meter tu frontend en src/main/resources/static alli puedes crear varias carpetas también, para separar las cosas. Recuerda que la aplicación se ejecuta en un tomcat embebido y los archivos estaticos deben estar dentro del war o ear, a menos que hagas las configuraciones necesarias, de alli que solo te funcione cuando los copias.

Comment: Preguntas si hay que agregar la propiedades de conexión al archivo properties, la respuesta es que si, sino la aplicación no va a saber a dónde conectarse ni con qué credenciales. Para conectar en java veo éste link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-java y allí lo hacen creando un bean de igual manera en la configuración del add-on de postgres te indican los datos que puedes colocar allí.

Comment: ok,gracias ahora voy a probar